# WSUS not working on clients - deployed via GPO

Tags: wsus

I've deployed WSUS on a server called INet
This has downloaded the required updates that I selected.

I've configured automatic updates in the GPO -
Set the following:

- Allow Automatic Updates immediate installation
- Allow non-administrators to receive update notifications
- Specify intranet Microsoft update service location:
  (I set this to http://INet)

I also set the time to check for updates to 4pm (for testing)

I linked the GPO in the relevant OU, then signed on to a test computer (windows xp pro)
Logged in, checked the Update tab in My Computer, and it was grayed out, with 4pm set as the update time (so i know the GPO had worked)

4pm came and went, but no updates....
Checked on INet server in the WSUS console, still showed 0 computers...

What have I missed?

**

> Edit / Update

**

I've now run "wuauclt /detectnow" and it has put some errors in the error log

**Failed to find updates with error code 80244019**

I also notice the url it is searching for is:
http://INet/ClientWebService/client.asmx

When i try this URL in IE from the client, I get a 404.
on looking on IIS on INet - i see the folder, but it is emtpy..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok,
I figured it out...

WSUS was installed on port 8530 for some reason... this may be the default port?
By changing my url in the GPO to http://INet:8530 it then worked.
I ran the wuauclt /detectnow command, and checked the error log.

There were a bunch of errors about Windows Installer 3.1 - then a balloon popped up, saying updates were ready etc..
I presume one of these updates will be the required Windows Installer 3.1

Comment: You have a choice during installation to install to a dedicated site, which defaults to port 8530. (Now I'm kicking myself that I didn't mention in my answer checking to see that you didn't install on a site running on port 8530... Grr...)

Comment: Yep, latest version of windows installer, bits etc are the first patches that will be installed before any others will be attempted.

Comment: I take it I'm not "missing out on any goodies" by installing it as it is? I mean... if i want to change it at some later date, all I need to do is alter my GPO? is that right? Thanks for your help Evan... I wouldn't of looked in the log otherwise!

Answer (score 2):

The %SystemRoot%\WindowsUpdate.log file is your friend. Assuming the "Automated Updates" service is started, you'll see the diagnostic output from the process there.

That's all I can really say w/o knowing more detail.

Comment: I've had a look through.. and theres nothing 5 mins either side of 4pm... so it looks like it didn't even try it?

Comment: Polsy is correct in his statement that the time (4PM, in your case) is when the updates are *installed*, not when they're detected. Detection can happen at any time, and is on a once per 22 hours schedule, by default, just like he says.

Comment: What else are you seeing in that file, though? Is it contacting your intranet update server at all? Are you seeing any errors?

Comment: The worlds most verbose, and unreadable log.  Ever :)

Comment: Ok, now when i run that cmd, i see in the error log... amongst other things... 0x80244019

Comment: http://inetexplorer.mvps.org/archive/wuc.htm has been (sometimes) useful to me for diagonising Windows Update things. Apparently that one represents a 404 error, so possibly something's up with the web server end. I'm not sure where to look to help with that, though.

Answer (score 1):

The time in the Automatic Updates configuration is the time when downloaded updates are installed, the check will stay on its usual schedule (see Automatic Updates detection frequency, default every 22 hours). Running 'wuauclt /detectnow' will trigger an immediate detection.

Comment: I don't have documentation handy that says so, but I had a recollection that detection would be triggered immediately if the update source changed.